# Como usar o comando between no codeigniter para gerar relatório

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Preciso de gerar o seguinte relatório:

O usuário seleciona o intervalo de tempo (data início e data fim) e o relatório de receitas é gerado exibindo o valor das receitas somados.

Segue a foto da view que chama a função na classe Model:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da View (foto acima):

```
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-11"> 
    <div class="page-header">
        <h4 align="center"><strong>Relatório de Receitas</strong></h4>
    </div>                       
    <form action="<?= base_url() ?>receita/pagas" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5" >                                           
                <label>Data do recebimento entre:</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4" >                                           
                <div id="datepicker1" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input id="dtrecinicio" class="form-control" type="text" name="dtrecinicio" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
                            autoclose: true,
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            language: "pt-BR"
                        }).dtrecinicio('update', new Date());
                    });
                </script>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> 
                <label>E</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">                   
                <div id="datepicker2" class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                    <input id="dtrecfim" class="form-control" type="text" name="dtrecfim" required>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function () {
                        $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
                            autoclose: true,
                            todayHighlight: true,
                            language: "pt-BR"
                        }).dtrecfim('update', new Date());
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>                
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row">            
            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">GERAR</button>                
                    </div>
                </div>                               
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">                 
            <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-md btn-default btn-block hidden-print" href="<?= base_url(); ?>">CANCELAR</a>
                    </div>
                </div>                                        
            </div>                                        
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Função da Classe Model:

```
    function get_receitas_like() {
        $inicio = $this->input->post('dtrecinicio');
        $fim = $this->input->post('dtrecfim');
//        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->select_sum("valor_receita");

        $this->db->where('dtrecebimento' >= $inicio);
        $this->db->where('dtrecebimento' <= $fim);
//        $this->db->where('dtrecebimento' BETWEEN  AND $dtrecebimento2');
//        $this->db->where('dtrecebimento', $termo);
        return $this->db->get('receitas')->result();
    }
```

Código da View que exibe os dados somados:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p align="center"><font  size="3" face="helvetica"><u><strong>RELATÓRIO - RECEITAS</strong></u></font></p>                                                           
        </div>
    </div>          
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="table-responsive"> 
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr class="row">                         
                        <td><strong>Valor total recebido no período selecionado:</strong> R$ <?php echo number_format($receitas[0]->valor_receita,2,",","."); ?></td>                                                                                             
                    </tr>                     
                    <tr class="row">                                   
                        <td></td> 
                        <td></td>                                                        
                    </tr>                     
                </table>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Foto da tabela Receitas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas modificações:

Se sua data está no formato correto a data que vem da tela não está, precisa ser convertida para Date e depois na SQL passa a formatação correspondente, exemplo:

```
$inicio = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->input->post('dtrecinicio'));
$fim = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $this->input->post('dtrecfim'));
```

e mude:

```
$this->db->where('dtrecebimento' >= $inicio));
$this->db->where('dtrecebimento' <= $fim);
```

para

```
$this->db->where('dtrecebimento >=', $inicio->format('Y-m-d'));
$this->db->where('dtrecebimento <=', $fim->format('Y-m-d'));
```

os sinais tem que ficar dentro do primeiro parâmetro.

<sub>**Referencia:** [Custom Where](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#id2)</sub>

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno @Virgilio Novic só que apesar da sintaxe correta do "where" a soma não está sendo feita de forma correta, está gerando um número muito alto, não condizente com os dados do banco.

Comment: @Ramiro é o seguinte a sintaxe é essa para `between` entre valores no caso data e a sua duvida era sobre isso, se a soma está vindo diferente é porque está faltando alguma coisa antes, você na sua pergunta poderia disponibilizar mais informações, tipo eu tenho esse conjunto de informações e o resultado da soma é !!! pra gente pode ajudar mais... essa parte da data foi solucionada, agora a SQL antes não está bem clara na pergunta se puder atualizar a pergunta podemos ajudar.

Comment: Ok @Virgilio Novic consegui resolver meu problema com o 'like' mesmo, pois com o between não sei porque a soma gerada estava vindo errada. Obrigado mais uma vez.